# How to share folder between host Ubuntu and already running Docker container on it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am using Amazon ECS, and launched the EC2 instance with ECS Linux AMI. On that EC2 instance I have multiple Docker containers each running different-different applications.

I wanted to create a folder on host, where I can add/edit anything and will get reflected to a shared folder from docker container. I have tried using following command:

```
docker run --name {new_container_name} -d -p 80:80 -v /{source folder}:/{destination folder}:ro {container name}
```

I referred [to this link](http://takacsmark.com/getting-started-with-docker-in-your-project-step-by-step-tutorial/).

Actual Result - it will creates a new container with similar to as {container name}.

But, what I want is, I need a way with which I can create a shared folder with the current running Docker container. How can I do that?